# rdkit: How to show molecular's atoms number

Tags: numbers, display, rdkit, moleculer

Hello1
I was trying to use rdkit pack to finish the work of displaying the molecular's atom numbers in Jupyter Notebook ,"import IPython.core.interactiveshell" and "import InteractiveShell" ,and "from rdkit.Chem.Draw import DrawingOptions" packs,then I was using "DrawingOptions.includeAtomNumbers=True" to work it ,but the result didn't display the atoms index at all .
I don't konw what 's the reason lead to the atoms number didn't showed.
So I want to please you to give an answer fittable.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

There are three ways to show atom numbers in the molecule.

```py
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem.Draw import IPythonConsole

def show_atom_number(mol, label):
    for atom in mol.GetAtoms():
        atom.SetProp(label, str(atom.GetIdx()+1))
    return mol
```

**1. In place of the atoms**

```py
mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles('c1ccccc(C(N)=O)1')
show_atom_number(mol, 'atomLabel')
```

[image]

**2. Along with the atoms**

```py
mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles('c1ccccc(C(N)=O)1')
show_atom_number(mol, 'molAtomMapNumber')
```

[image]

**3. On top of the atoms**

```py
mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles('c1ccccc(C(N)=O)1')
show_atom_number(mol, 'atomNote')
```

[image]

If you want to change the numbers to display, change the part `str(atom.GetIdx()+1)` as per your requirements. Checkout my blog post on the same for more detailed explanation [here](https://chemicbook.com/2021/03/01/how-to-show-atom-numbers-in-rdkit-molecule.html)

Answer (score 4):

This works for me in a Jupyter Notebook:

```
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem.Draw import IPythonConsole
from rdkit.Chem import Draw

smiles = 'O=C(C)Oc1ccccc1C(=O)O'
mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smiles)
Draw.MolToImage(mol, includeAtomNumbers=True)
```

**Update**

As of version `2020.03.1` this did not work anymore.

But you can annotate atoms directly.

```
from rdkit import Chem

smiles = 'O=C(C)Oc1ccccc1C(=O)O'
mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smiles)
for atom in mol.GetAtoms():
    atom.SetProp('atomLabel',str(atom.GetIdx()))
```

Comment: Anyone knows since when this drawing feature is included in rdkit?

Comment: @KareemJeiroudi I do not know since when this feature is included, but it seems that in the actual version `2020.03.1` it is broken.

Comment: @repelpy one of my colleagues encountered the same problem with the 2020 release

Comment: @KareemJeiroudi Updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

In version 2020.03.2.0 you could try

```
from rdkit.Chem.Draw import rdMolDraw2D
from rdkit import Chem

mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles('c1ccccc1O')
d = rdMolDraw2D.MolDraw2DCairo(250, 200)
d.drawOptions().addAtomIndices = True
d.DrawMolecule(mol)
d.FinishDrawing()
with open('atom_annotation_1.png', 'wb') as f:   
    f.write(d.GetDrawingText())
```